# Jquery validation not working - return conflicts

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, conflict, cakephp-2.3

Iam developing a website in cakephp.

The all js files loaded n footer.ctp view page.

This is my footer page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/modernizr.custom.17475.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/jquery.selectbox-0.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/stickytooltip.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/event-menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/custom-sub.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/easyResponsiveTabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/jquery.tagcloud.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//$('#Select_Access_1').selectbox();
$(function () {
    var total_ul_count = "";
    if($("#total_ul_count")) {
        total_ul_count = $("#total_ul_count").val();
    }

    if(total_ul_count) {
        var arr = total_ul_count.split(',');
        $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
                $('#Select_Access_'+value).selectbox();
        });
    }

    $(".delete_row").on('click', function () {
        var myid = $(this).attr('id');
        var my_i_val = myid.substring(13);

        delete_subscribe_emails(my_i_val);

        $("#li_"+my_i_val).remove();
        var count_str = $("#total_ul_count").val();
        arr = count_str.split(',');
        arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(value) {
          return value != my_i_val;
        });
        arr_str = arr.join();
        $("#total_ul_count").val(arr_str);
  });   

  $(".delete-subscribes").on('click', function () {
        var myid = $(this).attr('id');
        var my_i_val = myid.substring(7);

        delete_notify_emails(my_i_val);

        $("#subscribe_"+my_i_val).remove();
        var count_str = $("#Subcribes_list_numbers").val();
        arr = count_str.split(',');
        arr = jQuery.grep(arr, function(value) {
          return value != my_i_val;
        });
        arr_str = arr.join();
        $("#Subcribes_list_numbers").val(arr_str);
 });
});
</script>


<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/common-scripts1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/JQValidation/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Add_Organization").validate({
           submitHandler: function(form) {
               //window.location='http://go.registerguard.com/entertainment/';
               alert(1);
               return false;
             },
        });



});

var jQuerX = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Now all are working, but the submitHandler not working.

We are facing this issues at first time...

So this issues to be very strange to me....

How can i solve this, we also tried nonconflict, but still have issues.

**UPDATE**

We are using responsive tabs. Because of this may or may not the jquery validate work..
I jquery validate is worked, then tabs not working..
 If tab worked worked , then validation not worked...

This is the view page:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="organization-details-content">
        <aside>
          <div id="organizationTab">
          <?php
          if(isset($this->request->data['Organization']) && $this->request->data['Organization']['id'] != "") {
                echo $this->Form->input('Organization.id', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'OrganizationId',
                                                                    'type' => 'hidden',
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field',
                                                                    'readonly' => 'readonly')); 
          } else { 
                echo $this->Form->input('Organization.id', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'OrganizationId',
                                                                    'type' => 'hidden',
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field',
                                                                    'readonly' => 'readonly')); 
          }
          echo $this->Form->input('Organization.tab2', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'OrganizationTab2',
                                                                    'type' => 'hidden',
                                                                    'value'=>$tab2,
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field',
                                                                    'readonly' => 'readonly')); 
          ?>

            <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
              <li id="basicinfo-tab">Basic Information</li>
              <li id="analytics-tab">Analytics</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="resp-tabs-container">
              <div id="basicinfo">
              <?php echo $this->Form->create('Organization', array('id' => 'Add_Organization','nonvalidate'=>'nonvalidate')); ?>
                <div class="organization-details">
                  <h1>Basic Information</h1>
                  <p><strong>Your organization will be your public face on Central Ticketing Sales, promotions and reporting will be managed through your organization.</strong></p>
                  <div class="basic_info">
                    <ul>
                      <li><span class="org1"><img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>images/create-org1.png" alt="1" /></span>Create an Organization</li>
                      <li><span class="event2"><img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>images/create-event2.png" alt="2" /></span>Create an Event</li>
                      <li><span class="tickets"><img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>images/sell-ticket3.png" alt="2" /></span>Sell Tickets</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="organization_field">
                    <label>What is the name of your Organization</label>
                    <div class="org_field">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Organization.name', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'name',
                                                                    'type' => 'text',
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field')); ?>
                      <span> This could be the name of your company, non-profit, group, school, etc.</span> </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="organization-details">
                  <h2>Contact Information for Central Tickets</h2>
                  <p>Please enter the email and phone number through which you would like CentralTicket to contact your organization. </p>
                  <div class="organization_field">
                    <div class="filed-margin-bottom">
                      <label class="label-width">Email</label>
                      <div class="org_field">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($this->request->data['Organization']) && $this->request->data['Organization']['company_email'] != "") {
                            echo $this->Form->input('Organization.company_email', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'company_email',
                                                                    'type' => 'text',
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field'));
                        } else {
                            echo $this->Form->input('Organization.company_email', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'company_email',
                                                                    'type' => 'text',
                                                                    'value'=> 'abcd@email.com',
                                                                    'onblur'=>"javascript:if(this.value==''){this.value='abcd@email.com'}",
                                                                    'onfocus'=>"javascript:if(this.value=='abcd@email.com'){this.value=''}",
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field'));
                        }
                         ?>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filed-margin-bottom">
                      <label class="label-width">Phone</label>
                      <div class="org_field">
                        <?php 
                        if(isset($this->request->data['Organization']) && $this->request->data['Organization']['contact_phone'] != "") {
                            echo $this->Form->input('Organization.contact_phone', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'contact_phone',
                                                                    'type' => 'text',
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field'));
                        } else {
                            echo $this->Form->input('Organization.contact_phone', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'contact_phone',
                                                                    'type' => 'text',
                                                                    'value'=> '+971502504858',
                                                                    'onblur'=>"javascript:if(this.value==''){this.value='+971502504858'}",
                                                                    'onfocus'=>"javascript:if(this.value=='+971502504858'){this.value=''}",
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field'));
                        }
                         ?>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filed-margin-bottom">
                    <label class="label-width label-hide">&nbsp;</label>
                      <div class="button-container">
                       <?php echo $this->Form->input('Page.step', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'step',
                                                                    'type' => 'hidden',
                                                                    'readonly' => 'readonly',
                                                                    'value'=> 'basicinfo',
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field')); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save Changes', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                            'name'=>'basicinfo_save',
                                                                            'id'=>'basicinfo_save', 
                                                                            'type' => 'submit', 
                                                                            'class'=>'org-button')); ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
              </div>
              <!--1st Tab conent end here-->

              <!--2nd Tab conent end here-->

              <div id="analytics">
               <?php echo $this->Form->create('Add_Organization_Web', array('id' => 'Add_Organization_Web')); ?>
                <div class="organization-details">
                  <h1>Analytics</h1>
                  <h3>Google Analytics Tracking </h3>
                  <p>You can use Google Analytics to track your events. To set up Google Analytics for your organization:</p>
                  <ul class="tracking-list">
                    <li>Follow our Google Analytics Tracking How-to to set up your domain.</li>
                    <li>Enter your Google Analytics Web Property ID below.</li>
                  </ul>
                  <p>We will immediately start sending visitor and transaction data to your Google Analytics account. It can take up to a day for your traffic to show up in your Google Analytics account.</p>
                  <p>Sending visitor and transaction data to Google Analytics relies on the browser of your visitors. There are no guarantees that a visitor's browser will have the capabilities required for sending this data to Google Analytics. Some discrepancies may arise between the statistics in Google Analytics and in your Central Ticketing admin.</p>
                  <div class="organization_field">
                    <div class="filed-margin-bottom">
                      <label class="label-width">Web Property ID </label>
                      <div class="org_field margin">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Organization.Web_ID', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'Web_ID',
                                                                    'type' => 'text',
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field')); ?>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="filed-margin-bottom">
                       <label class="label-width label-hide">&nbsp;</label>
                      <div class="button-container">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Page.step', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                                    'id'=>'step',
                                                                    'type' => 'hidden',
                                                                    'readonly' => 'readonly',
                                                                    'value'=> 'webinfo',
                                                                    'class'=>'input-field')); ?>

                        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save Changes', array('div'=>false, 
                                                                            'name'=>'webinfo_save',
                                                                            'id'=>'webinfo_save', 
                                                                            'type' => 'button', 
                                                                            'class'=>'org-button')); ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
              </div>
              <!--4nd Tab conent end here--> 

            </div>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
```

Comment: `<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/JQValidation/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` i think this is not needed as you have loaded a jquery library already.

Comment: but when i removed that js file , the responsive tab not working.....

Comment: If you want help with jQuery Validate, which is ***client-side*** code, then only show us the relevant ***rendered*** code as seen by the browser.

Comment: @Sparky , i updated the question with my view page ....can you check that..

Comment: @Sparky, the code i updated ............

Comment: PHP is not _"rendered code **as seen by the browser**"_

Answer (score 0):

I think you have loaded a jquery library  version `1.9+` so no need to load another library again. See you have this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
</script>
```

library loaded already, so you don't have to load this lib:

```
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/JQValidation/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

and you can try changing this line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Comment: `js/JQValidation/jquery-1.8.3.js` if you could show what do you have in this file. is this jquery library or you have some custom jquery written in this file.